# sharepoint lookup column, which values should not be duplicated

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to have a  sharepoint lookup column, which values should not be duplicated in the destination list.
Can be duplicated in source list.
I create and deploy the list through VS solution.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the following attributes on the lookup column definition

> EnforceUniqueValues = "TRUE"
>   Indexed = "TRUE"

```
SPField field = list.Fields["TestCol"];
field.Indexed = true;
field.EnforceUniqueValues = true;
field.Update();
```